# truncate nvarchar in mssql library when data more than 80k bytes

Tags: node.js

In mssql library in node.js when I save data in nvarchar column with more than 80K byte, mssql automatically truncated data.

What should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To setup MAX length for VarChar, NVarChar and VarBinary use sql.MAX length.